# macOS Sierra and QNAP SMB share - Disk does not support Time Machine backups. (error 45)

Tags: backup, time-machine, macos, nas, smb

Quote from [macOS Sierra: Disks you can use with Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25585?locale=en_US)

> If your backup disk is on a network, the network server can use Server
>   Message Block (SMB) file sharing. Your Mac must be connected to the
>   SMB server when you set up Time Machine. After you select the network
>   disk in Time Machine preferences, Time Machine automatically connects
>   to the disk when it’s time to back up or restore your data.

```
> sudo tmutil setdestination "/Volumes/$NAME/"                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Password:
/Volumes/$NAME: Disk does not support Time Machine backups. (error 45)
The backup destination could not be set.
```

I use QNAP TS-251 with latest firmware. The SMB share is working fine with Finder.

Any idea? I don't wish to use AFP.

I followed the instructions [How do I set up Time Machine backups between my Mac and NAS on a domain via the SMB protocol?](https://www.qnap.com/en/qa/con_show.php?op=showone&cid=671). When mounted as SMB it doesn't work, but with AFP it works.

Comment: Fedor! And what is the result? SMB works? I looking for NAS to replace Time Capsule and looking at QNAP.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue on the QNAP w/ latest firmware using high sierra

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score -3):

QNAP says it is not supported!

Comment: whats your source? please paste original quote from vendor support